# how to access SharedPrefrence value throughout the app? its value become null after i close the app?

Tags: flutter, dart

My home page is Displayed Based on the `UserType` value that I set in SharedPreffrence, for the first time when I run The app it works fine and the home page is displayed Successfully  because it knows the values of `Usertype` from SharedPreference, but when I close the app and run again The value of `UserType become Null`, due to this my home page is not Displayed because `Usertype` value is `null`, I set SharedPreference when the user login for The first time,

As you See in my code First I pass the value of UserType from SharedPreference, and also I Call `Get()` method in `initState()`, to Call SharedPrefrence.

Here is how I set SharedPreference when the user Login for the first time.

```
     Future loginWithEmailAndPasswords(String email, String password,BuildContext context) async {
  try {
          UserCredential register = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: email, password: password);
          User registredUser = register.user;
          final customSnapshots= await customSnapshot.doc(registredUser.uid).get();
       
          if(customSnapshots.exists){
            SharedPreferences preferences= await SharedPreferences.getInstance() ;
            preferences.setString("UserType", customSnapshots.data()['Account type'].toString());

    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>homecontroller(
        controllUserType:preferences.getString('UserType'),
        userid: customSnapshots.data()['userId'].toString(),))); }
}
```

Here is My HomeController Page.

---

```
    class homecontroller extends StatelessWidget {
      final String controllUserType;
      final String userid;
       const homecontroller({Key key,@required this.controllUserType,@required this.userid}):super(key: key);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Authservice auth
        final Authservice auth=Provider.of(context).auth;
        return StreamBuilder(
              stream:auth.authStateChanges,
              builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<String>snapshot){
              if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.active){
                final bool SignedIn=snapshot.hasData;
                return SignedIn?HomePage(UserType:controllUserType,userID: userid,):firstview();
              }else{
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
              },
        );
      }
    }
```

---

Here is My home page

```
    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      final String UserType;
      final String userID;
    
      const HomePage({Key key,@required this.UserType,@required this.userID}):super(key: key);
      @override
      _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      bool isSignedIn= false;
      String owneruerID;
      dynamic uploadusertypes;
      List<Widget>_children;
      void initState(){
        super.initState();
        uploadusertypes= widget.UserType; //this value is passed from SharedPreference when the user login for the first time
        owneruerID = widget.userID;//this value is passed from SharedPreference when the user login for the first time
         GetData(); // here is Where i Call SharedPreference Method
        _children=[
          TimeLinePage(),
          SearchPage(), //search(),
          UploadPage(UserSID:owneruerID,uploadusertypes:uploadusertypes),
          NotificationsPage(),
          ProfilePage(userProfileID:widget.userID),
        ];
       
        if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!=null){
            setState(() {
              isSignedIn= true;
            });
          }else{
            setState(() {
              isSignedIn= false;
               });
          }
    
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      if(isSignedIn){
     if(widget.UserType== 'Customer')
        {
     return Scaffold(
       body: WillPopScope(
         onWillPop: onwillpops,
         child: buildHomeScreen()));
         }
 
      }
 void GetData()async {
    SharedPreferences preferences= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      widget.UserType=preferences.getString('UserType');
    });

  }
 }
```

Comment: It's a bit difficult to get the flow of code. Can you reduce the code length and try to make it minimal?

Comment: ok please wait? i will do that

Comment: And if it becomes null. Just re-read it.

Comment: AS you can see first I have a login page() when the user login for the first time, I create SharedPrefrence, and  pass UserType value, to the HomeController page()  as you can see  above i have HomeControllerpage() too, this page pass the UserType value  to the Homepage and displays the home page depending on the UsetType value,  here is my folder structure, login page()->HomeController()-> Homepage()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I am Doing is Just I Remove both uploadusertypes and owneruerID from InitState() and I Declared Them Inside Getdata(), it works but i don't know weather it have effect on my code or not,

```
 uploadusertypes= widget.UserType;
    owneruerID = widget.userID;

Here is what I am doing 

  void initState(){
     GetData();
    super.initState();
    _children=[
      TimeLinePage(),
      SearchPage(), //search(),
      UploadPage(UserSID:owneruerID,uploadusertypes:uploadusertypes),
      NotificationsPage(),
      ProfilePage(userProfileID:widget.userID),
    ];
    _agentchildren=[
      TimeLinePage(),
      SearchPage(), //search(),
      NotificationsPage(),
      ProfilePage(userProfileID:owneruerID),
    ];
      if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!=null){
        setState(() {
          isSignedIn= true;
        });
      }else{
        setState(() {
          isSignedIn= false;
           });
      }
    uploadusertypes= widget.UserType;
    owneruerID = widget.userID;
  }
```

---

```
 void GetData()async {
    SharedPreferences preferences= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      uploadusertypes=preferences.get('UserType');
      widget.UserType=preferences.get('UserType');
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think first you should call `GetData()` before the pass shared preference values to variables ( EX - UserType). Then you could get the `UserType` value and then could pass that value to `uploadusertypes`.

Try the following code.

```
    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      final String UserType;
      final String userID;
    
      const HomePage({Key key,@required this.UserType,@required this.userID}):super(key: key);
      @override
      _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      bool isSignedIn= false;
      String owneruerID;
      dynamic uploadusertypes;
      List<Widget>_children;
      void initState(){
        super.initState();
        GetData(); // you should call this one first. 
        uploadusertypes= widget.UserType; //this value is passed from SharedPreference when the user login for the first time
        owneruerID = widget.userID;//this value is passed from SharedPreference when the user login for the first time
        
        _children=[
          TimeLinePage(),
          SearchPage(), //search(),
          UploadPage(UserSID:owneruerID,uploadusertypes:uploadusertypes),
          NotificationsPage(),
          ProfilePage(userProfileID:widget.userID),
        ];
       
        if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!=null){
            setState(() {
              isSignedIn= true;
            });
          }else{
            setState(() {
              isSignedIn= false;
               });
          }
    
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      if(isSignedIn){
     if(widget.UserType== 'Customer')
        {
     return Scaffold(
       body: WillPopScope(
         onWillPop: onwillpops,
         child: buildHomeScreen()));
         }
 
      }
 void GetData()async {
    SharedPreferences preferences= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      widget.UserType=preferences.getString('UserType');
    });

  }
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.